# TextField size is not increasing in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to design a simple interface with `JFrame`, `JPanel`, `JButton`, `JLabel`, `JTextField` and `JPasswordField` using `GridBagLayout` and `GridBagConstraints`. Also if anyone tell me how can I span textfield in 2 columns when I there are only 2 controls are available.

See the output I am getting

[image]

Look TextField and PasswordField how they are I am trying to get bigger size but failed see the code I used.

All the required classes are imported

```
public class login extends JFrame{
private JPanel jPanelC,jPanelE,jPanelW,jPanelN,jPanelS;
private JLabel jlabel1,jlabel2,jlabel3;
private JTextField jid;
private JPasswordField jpass;
private JButton jbutton1;
Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

public login()
{
    jPanelC=new JPanel();
    jlabel1=new JLabel("User ID");
    jlabel2=new JLabel("Password");
    jlabel3=new JLabel("Password");
    jid=new JTextField(15);
    jid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    jpass=new JPasswordField(15);
    jpass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    jbutton1=new JButton("Login");
    jbutton1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    jPanelC.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    jPanelC.setBorder(empty);
    int eb=5;
    jPanelC.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb), // outer border
    BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder()));      // inner border
    jPanelC.setSize(300, 150);

    jPanelC.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    jPanelC.add(jlabel1,c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    jPanelC.add(jid,c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    jPanelC.add(jlabel2,c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    jPanelC.add(jpass,c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;      
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;

   jPanelC.add(jbutton1,c);

    jPanelE=new JPanel();
    jPanelW=new JPanel();
    jPanelN=new JPanel();
    jPanelS=new JPanel();
    add(jPanelE,BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(jPanelW,BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(jPanelN,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jPanelS,BorderLayout.SOUTH);       
    add(jPanelC,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Login Console");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setSize(400, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);       
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    login log=new login();
}
```

After adding c.weightx=1; Final output

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`GridBagConstraints.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) and [`GridBahConstraints.ipad[xy]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipadx)

Comment: @msrd0 Thanx for suggestion I tried my options including yours but result is nothing, can you show some code example

Comment: Sorry, I meant `weight[xy]`, see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment these lines of code**

```
jid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
...
jpass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
...
jbutton1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
```

You will get this result:

[image]

If you want the `Login` button at the center, you can put the `UserID` and `password` (label and input fields) in a panel and add that panel to the `jPanelC`. You might get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the weight along the X axis so that the components expand in that direction

```
c.weightx = 1;
```

Comment: @msrd0 done but now space between the jLabel1 and jTextField is also increased and Jlabel gone at left and JTextfield gone at right side. See the image in my first post

Comment: consider uploading an image of the end result

Comment: @msrd0 uploaded the image after the change see the edited post

Comment: @msrd0 What about the gap came between label and textfield this is not expected

Answer (score 1):

Set the weight

```
c.weightx = 1;
```

and to fix the button after
your objects start on grid.x 2 and end at 3.  So the width for one that fills the whole page should be three

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 2;      
c.gridheight=1;
```

//---------------------------

```
c.gridwidth = 3;
```

or change the starting x point for your textfields to one